# How to concatenate project SOAPUI variables in a test Request?

Tags: soap, soapui, soap-client

I have defined test suite properties as msisdn and imsi. Is there any way that both the variables are substituted for their values. I can get only the last variable to be substituted.

**${properties#imsi}${#properties#msisdn}**

Only value for msisdn gets replaced

Comment: How are you using? in a soap request? or in a groovy? And how are you expecting the output?

Comment: Is that `#` missed in the first one before properties? i.e., `${#properties#imsi}${#properties#msisdn}`

Comment: Thanks Rao for your pointer. Its actually the # that was causing issue. I am using in SOAP Request not in groovy.  <subscriberId>123456789090909909090909090</subscriberId> is the desired output when I used  <subscriberId>${properties#imsi}${properties#msisdn}</subscriberId>

Comment: Can I add it as answer then?

Comment: Removing the # solved the issue. I was referring to properties within the test suite. This properties here is not scope. its the name of the property variable.